# getting position of collada model in three.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, three.js, webgl

I    have     created    a    simple     life     bar     using     css.

```
#enemy {
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 7px;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 100px;
}

#enemy div {
    background-color: green;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

I    have   to   move    the    bar    on    top    of   the    head    of    my    collada    model. how   can    i    assign    position   of    model    to    bar   using    jQuery? here is the code i tried but it doesn't work

```
    var count =0;
        for (var i = ai.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            var a = ai[i];
            // Move AI
        var r = Math.random();
            var c = getMapSector(a.position);

$('#enemy div').css({'position':'relative', 'top':c.z, 'left':c.x,});

            if (c.x < -1 || c.x > mapW || c.z < -1 || c.z > mapH) {
                ai.splice(i, 1);
                scene.remove(a);
                addAI();
            }
            }


function getMapSector(v) {
    var x = Math.floor((v.x + UNITSIZE / 2) / UNITSIZE + mapW/2);
    var z = Math.floor((v.z + UNITSIZE / 2) / UNITSIZE + mapW/2);
    return {x: x, z: z};
}
```

Comment: Is the model the only thing being rendered in a canvas, or are you looking for the pixel location of where the model is being rendered within the canvas? If it's the former, it would be a matter of placing the bar above where the canvas is.

Comment: @Jacob no there are multiple models and i have to place the bar on each of them.