# Get Three.js camera to use position from Sketchup Collada export

Tags: three.js

I have created a very simple model in Sketchup and exported it as a collada file. I am then trying to get three.js to display the model with the same view that was exported from Sketchup. The view in Sketchup had been panned and rotated.
If I load the model into the tree.js editor and select the skp_camera_Last_Saved_SketchUp_View camera then it appears as it did in Sketchup.

[Editor Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIBjh.png)

When I load the model using my code the camera position is incorrect

[My result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7Rmj.png)

It is obvious that my camera is looking at 0,0,0 and I sense that the answer is here [getting position of collada model in three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16308871/getting-position-of-collada-model-in-three-js) but I can't make it work. I have also tried to work through the editor source code to no avail.

Below is my code and model

```
<script type="module">
        import * as THREE from '../build/three.module.js';
        import { ColladaLoader } from '../examples/jsm/loaders/ColladaLoader.js';

        let container
        let camera, scene, renderer, model;

        init(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

        function init(imageWidth, imageHeight) {
            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            var grid1 = new THREE.GridHelper(30, 30, 0x888888);
            grid1.material.color.setHex(0x888888);
            grid1.material.vertexColors = false;
            scene.add(grid1);

            const loadingManager = new THREE.LoadingManager(function () { });
            const loader = new ColladaLoader(loadingManager);
            loader.load('./model.dae', function (collada) {
                model = collada.scene;
                scene.add(model);

                var cameras = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < model.children[0].children.length; i++) {
                    var child = model.children[0].children[i];
                    if (child.type == "PerspectiveCamera") {
                        cameras.push(child);
                    }
                }

                camera = cameras[0];
                camera.aspect = imageWidth / imageHeight;

                const axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper(115);
                scene.add(axesHelper);

                const pointlight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1);
                pointlight.position.set(5, 10, 7.5);
                scene.add(pointlight);

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true,alpha: true });
                renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
                renderer.setSize(imageWidth, imageHeight);
                container = document.getElementById('container');
                container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

                var vector = new THREE.Vector3();
                camera.lookAt(vector);
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix()

                var vector = new THREE.Vector3();
                //vector.setFromMatrixPosition( model.matrixWorld );
                camera.lookAt( vector );                
                renderer.render(scene, camera);

            });
        }
    </script>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<COLLADA xmlns="http://www.collada.org/2005/11/COLLADASchema" version="1.4.1">
    <asset>
        <contributor>
            <authoring_tool>SketchUp 21.1.332</authoring_tool>
        </contributor>
        <created>2021-11-18T10:42:11Z</created>
        <modified>2021-11-18T10:42:11Z</modified>
        <unit meter="0.0254" name="inch" />
        <up_axis>Z_UP</up_axis>
    </asset>
    <library_cameras>
        <camera id="ID1" name="skp_camera_Last_Saved_SketchUp_View">
            <optics>
                <technique_common>
                    <perspective>
                        <yfov>35</yfov>
                        <aspect_ratio>0</aspect_ratio>
                        <znear>1</znear>
                        <zfar>1000</zfar>
                    </perspective>
                </technique_common>
            </optics>
        </camera>
    </library_cameras>
    <library_visual_scenes>
        <visual_scene id="ID2">
            <node name="SketchUp">
                <instance_geometry url="#ID3">
                    <bind_material>
                        <technique_common>
                            <instance_material symbol="Material2" target="#ID5">
                                <bind_vertex_input semantic="UVSET0" input_semantic="TEXCOORD" input_set="0" />
                            </instance_material>
                        </technique_common>
                    </bind_material>
                </instance_geometry>
                <node name="skp_camera_Last_Saved_SketchUp_View">
                    <matrix>0.9163804 -0.1783003 0.3584076 217.3235 0.4003086 0.4081623 -0.8204612 -203.3304 -1.110223e-16 0.8953282 0.445407 171.1284 0 0 0 1</matrix>
                    <instance_camera url="#ID1" />
                </node>
            </node>
        </visual_scene>
    </library_visual_scenes>
    <library_geometries>
        <geometry id="ID3">
            <mesh>
                <source id="ID6">
                    <float_array id="ID9" count="72">109.5625 0 0 0 0 0 0 118.5 0 109.5625 118.5 0 0 0 0 109.5625 0 0 109.5625 0 34.6875 0 0 34.6875 0 118.5 0 0 0 0 0 0 34.6875 0 118.5 34.6875 109.5625 118.5 0 0 118.5 0 0 118.5 34.6875 109.5625 118.5 34.6875 109.5625 0 0 109.5625 118.5 0 109.5625 118.5 34.6875 109.5625 0 34.6875 0 0 34.6875 109.5625 0 34.6875 109.5625 118.5 34.6875 0 118.5 34.6875</float_array>
                    <technique_common>
                        <accessor count="24" source="#ID9" stride="3">
                            <param name="X" type="float" />
                            <param name="Y" type="float" />
                            <param name="Z" type="float" />
                        </accessor>
                    </technique_common>
                </source>
                <source id="ID7">
                    <float_array id="ID10" count="72">0 0 -1 0 0 -1 0 0 -1 0 0 -1 0 -1 0 0 -1 0 0 -1 0 0 -1 0 -1 -0 -0 -1 -0 -0 -1 -0 -0 -1 -0 -0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 -0 0 1 -0 0 1 -0 0 1 -0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1</float_array>
                    <technique_common>
                        <accessor count="24" source="#ID10" stride="3">
                            <param name="X" type="float" />
                            <param name="Y" type="float" />
                            <param name="Z" type="float" />
                        </accessor>
                    </technique_common>
                </source>
                <vertices id="ID8">
                    <input semantic="POSITION" source="#ID6" />
                    <input semantic="NORMAL" source="#ID7" />
                </vertices>
                <polylist count="6" material="Material2">
                    <input offset="0" semantic="VERTEX" source="#ID8" />
                    <vcount>4 4 4 4 4 4</vcount>
                    <p>0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23</p>
                </polylist>
            </mesh>
        </geometry>
    </library_geometries>
    <library_materials>
        <material id="ID5" name="material">
            <instance_effect url="#ID4" />
        </material>
    </library_materials>
    <library_effects>
        <effect id="ID4">
            <profile_COMMON>
                <technique sid="COMMON">
                    <lambert>
                        <diffuse>
                            <color>1 1 1 1</color>
                        </diffuse>
                    </lambert>
                </technique>
            </profile_COMMON>
        </effect>
    </library_effects>
    <scene>
        <instance_visual_scene url="#ID2" />
    </scene>
</COLLADA>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am facing exactly the same issue. I am a beginner with three.js. I did two things to solve the problem:

1. convert camera position to meters. Although my SketchUp model was defined in meters, the exported collada file was in inches (look at the `<asset>` section at the top of your file). It seems that the three.js converts well the geometry in meters (I may be wrong) but keeps the camera position in inches. So when you add the `camera` to your scene, first scale the coordinates to obtain meters. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/16947400/2887058)
2. remove/comment the `<up_axis>` from your collada file. I don't know why (again, I am a novice in 3D modelling), but it fixed my problem

It would be great to understand how the three.js editor does everything fine by default.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use camera.lookAt(), the camera has already inherited the necessary settings from the Collada model. If you simply call camera.updateProjectionMatrix(), the view will match that of the SketchUp scene.

If you change the below portion of your code:

```
var vector = new THREE.Vector3();
camera.lookAt(vector);
camera.updateProjectionMatrix()

var vector = new THREE.Vector3();
//vector.setFromMatrixPosition( model.matrixWorld );
camera.lookAt( vector );                
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

To the following:

```
camera.updateProjectionMatrix()             
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

The camera should match SketchUp.